# If-Else conditions with APL?

Tags: if-statement, apl, gnu-apl

So, I'm wondering/asking; Is it possible to do an If-Statement in APL? If so how?

Here's my code

```
    'Please enter a number to count to: ' 
 number ←⎕ 
 ⍳number
```

How do I get an if-statement to where if the user inputs a number over 100 it will print out "too high" and end; or if it's 100 or under then it will just continue?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional function in APL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752895/conditional-function-in-apl)

Answer (score 9):

In Dyalog APL you have this neat little thing called guards.

They can be used in dfns and evaluate code when a certain condition matches.

```
func ← {⍵>100 : 'too high' ⋄ 1 : 'number is ok'}
```

Comment: Why did someone down-vote this answer? The explanation is a little short, but it is a very modern and clean way of answering. You can try it here: http://tryapl.org/

Comment: What is the significance of the `1 : ` part (in the false branch after `⋄`)?

Answer (score 6):

If your APL supports control structures then this should work:

```
∇ generateAll number
:If number>100
   ⎕←'Too high'
:else
   ⎕←⍳ number
:endif
∇
```

If it does NOT support control structures (like APL2) you will need to branch:

```
∇ generateAll number
 →(number>100)/error
 ⎕←⍳ number
 →0
error:
 ⎕←'Too high'
∇
```

You can also use tricks like execute but this is less readable.

Comment: the code display is all messed up, there should be 6 lines in each program shown above: a header line and 5 lines of code...

Comment: The second example (without control structures) should be correct for GNU APL.

Comment: I tried all of these but none of them seem to really  work. The second one for this one; I enter a number(both over and under 100) and it just stops at '∇ generateAll number' :/

Comment: I think you misunderstood something. `generateAll` is a function and needs to be entered/defined as such. (I can't comment on how to do this in GnuAPL). Then you can enter `generateAll 50`in the session to execute the function.

Answer (score 3):

A "classical" way of doing error handling* in APL2 is with the ⎕ES or ⎕EA.
Your code would look something like this:

```
⎕ES(NUMBER>100)/'Too high'
⍳NUMBER
```

What happens here is that **IF** the parentheses evaluate to true, **THEN** the `⎕ES` will halt the execution and echo the quoted string.

If you don't want your THEN to terminate, have a look at `⎕EA` in some APL documentation.

Please note that I'm on APL2 in a GreenOnBlack environment, so there are likely more neat ways of doing this in a more modern dialect like Dyalog.

---

*I know you're asking about conditionals and not error handling, but since you're example terminates execution, it might as well be error handling.

There is a crucial difference between this and what MBaas suggests: His solution will gracefully exit the **current** function which might return a value. Using `⎕ES` or `⎕EA` with **terminate** all execution.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the dialect you're using. Some APL-Implementations support control-strucures, so you could write something like

```
:If number>100
   ⎕←'Too high'
   →0
:endif
⍳number
```

In "tradtional APL" you would probably do something like

```
⍎(number>100)/'⎕←''Too high'' ⋄ →0'
⍳number
```

Comment: None of those seem to be working :/ I enter a number over 500; "too high" isn't printed out and '⍳number' is ran. Basically what I'm trying to go for, is if it's too high, don't print out '⍳number' however if it's under 100, then do print it out.

Comment: Which APL are you using?

Comment: Well I believe I'm using GNU APL 1.5; not sure if that helps.

Comment: Well, such details will help those answering in providing a suitable reply, as it elimates guesswork about the dialect. The answer of meagar (edited by DanB) considers the major possible pathways and should also apply for your case. Pls. have a look at that and, if it answers, also accept that, so that the question is closed.  :-)

Comment: Unfortunately none of those seem to work. The second one prints out the numbers if it's under 100. However if I input a number over 100, 'too high' prints out as expected; but then I see a Syntax Error+ at →0, then it still prints out the numbers.

Comment: The reply of DanB answers perfectly. Let's focus on getthing that to work for you.